# Labels in ViewController changes dynamically when buttons on UIView is pressed

Tags: ios, uibutton, uilabel

I have a singleView App with a VieController and a UIView. In the ViewController I have 3 UILabels. And in the UIView, which is within the ViewController, I have 3 UIButtons with the titles A, B and C.

What I need is: when the user presses one of the buttons, A, B or C from the UIView they should appear in the 3 UILabels in the ViewController in the same order they where pressed.

So if the user wants an output in the ViewController which shows C, B and A then he has to press the button C first, followed by the B, followed by the A.

Another user may want an output in the ViewController to be B, C and A then he has to press the button B first, followed by the C, followed by the A.

I am only giving these examples to ensure that you understand my question correctly.

I have also drawn an illustration for you:

[Labels shown in order they where pressed](https://www.dropbox.com/s/un8g1wjkyxmc9ig/Question.png)

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Provided that I understood what are you trying to achieve, this showed be fairly straight forward. Keep NSMutableArray as property on your VC. Each time button it pressed add corresponding Label to array. Before you add element to array check array count a wether this element already exists in array(this existence check is not in demo). One array has three elements set their coordinates and display them. I should point out that these are not kind of question you should be posting at stackoverflow nevertheless I wrote a quick demo http://www.stringcode.co.uk/random/ButtonsLabelsDemo.zip. Hope it will help you.

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience and thanks for the answer which I hoped would be  little more detailed. The link you provided does not work.

Comment: Im sorry I edited the link, should work now, I hope once you looked at it everything becomes clear